# Trouble adding controls to TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tablelayoutpanel

The following code works only for the first row. Once in the next row, it appears at the bottom and works its way up. I've done this before in another application, so I referenced that code. Yet, I'm getting different results. I want the rows to go from top to bottom, not bottom to top.

Variable `whichcolumn = 2` at first because the first two textboxes are already created. Variable `whichRow = 0`. Variable `i = 2` and exists to give all controls a unique name. All columns exist before run time.

```
 Private Sub Add_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addBTN.Click
        If whichColumn < 8 Then
            Dim startTXT As New TextBox
            Dim endTXT As New TextBox
            startTXT.Name = "start" & i & "TXT"
            endTXT.Name = "end" & i & "TXT"
            rangesPanel.Controls.Add(startTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
            whichColumn += 1
            rangesPanel.Controls.Add(endTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
            whichColumn += 1
            If Label3.Visible = False Then
                Label3.Visible = True
                Label4.Visible = True
            ElseIf Label5.Visible = False Then
                Label5.Visible = True
                Label6.Visible = True
            ElseIf Label7.Visible = False Then
                Label7.Visible = True
                Label8.Visible = True
            End If
            i += 1
        Else
            rangesPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
            rangesPanel.RowCount += 1
            whichColumn = 0
            whichRow += 1
            Dim startTXT As New TextBox
            Dim endTXT As New TextBox
            startTXT.Name = "start" & i & "TXT"
            endTXT.Name = "end" & i & "TXT"
            rangesPanel.Controls.Add(startTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
            whichColumn += 1
            rangesPanel.Controls.Add(endTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
            whichColumn += 1
            i += 1
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Block includes line "startTXT.Name = "start" & i & "TXT"", but what is "i" in this case?  I do not see an instantiation or initialization of i.

Comment: Updated post. i = 2 and is incremented by one every two textboxes. This is so all controls have a unique name. Again, it starts off at 2 because the first set of textboxes were created before run time. They are start1TXT and end1TXT.

Comment: What are the properties regarding the rows of your TableLayoutPanel?  My guess is that the first row is set to fill, so what is happening is all that blank space in between the first row of text boxes and the second row of text boxes is actually the entire height of the first row in your TableLayoutPanel.  Turning on showing the grid lines will help you determine this so you can see exactly what the rows/columns of the panel are doing.

Comment: This code can only work if the panel already contains a row.  That row is wrong, is SizeType is Percent instead of AutoSize.  Which is why the additional rows end up on the bottom.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to change SizeType from Percent to Fixed. I honestly thought it was set to AutoSize, but it wasn't.

Comment: Also, +1 for suggesting to turn on grid lines. For future reference, the property is `CellBorderStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Add_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addBTN.Click
    If whichColumn < 8 Then
        Dim startTXT As New TextBox
        Dim endTXT As New TextBox
        startTXT.Name = "start" & i & "TXT"
        endTXT.Name = "end" & i & "TXT"
        rangesPanel.Controls.Add(startTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
        whichColumn += 1
        rangesPanel.Controls.Add(endTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
        whichColumn += 1
        If Label3.Visible = False Then
            Label3.Visible = True
            Label4.Visible = True
        ElseIf Label5.Visible = False Then
            Label5.Visible = True
            Label6.Visible = True
        ElseIf Label7.Visible = False Then
            Label7.Visible = True
            Label8.Visible = True
        End If
        i += 1
    Else
        rangesPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 22))
        rangesPanel.RowCount += 1
        whichColumn = 0
        whichRow += 1
        Dim startTXT As New TextBox
        Dim endTXT As New TextBox
        startTXT.Name = "start" & i & "TXT"
        endTXT.Name = "end" & i & "TXT"
        rangesPanel.Controls.Add(startTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
        whichColumn += 1
        rangesPanel.Controls.Add(endTXT, whichColumn, whichRow)
        whichColumn += 1
        i += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Changing `SizeType` from `Percent` to `Absolute`, on all rows, solved the issue.